# Mediation: only c path and b path are significant?

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, multiple-regression, structural-equation-modeling, mediation

I have done a mediation analysis in which nature contact is the independent variable, worrying is the mediator and depressive symptoms the dependent variable. I performed a mediation via PROCESS.

The results were:

- The total effect of nature contact on depression is significant (c path)
- The a path: nature contact on worrying is insignificant

However, when a multiple regression is done， in which both nature contact and worrying are in the model, the direct effect of nature contact on depressive symptoms is not significant. So c path is not significant in this same multiple regression, worrying is significant, so it seems like there is a full mediation. I have performed bootstrapping to see if the mediation is significant, which it wasn’t.

My hypotheses was that more nature contact is associated with less depression. Based on the total effect, I could say there is an effect. But is that claim still valid, knowing that there isn't a direct effect due to the presence of worrying in the multiple regression analysis?

Comment: Step back from the statistical significance for a second. What is the reason why each relationship looks the way it does from a theoretical standpoint? Also I personally don't know if I would trust the PROCESS macro with anything that incorporates less than perfect reliability (such as Likert scale measures like I presume you are using). Models fit with latent variable models like `lavaan` are potentially better at dealing with uncertainty and attenuation bias. MLR by itself isn't any better for similar reasons.

Comment: Thank you for your response Shawn! Based on literature, there should be a small effect of nature contact on depression. No research has been done before  on the relationship between nature contact and worrying. Based on the proven relationship between nature contact and rumination, i expected the same for worrying which wasnt the case. Unfortunately as I am a master’s student, I havent been thought to perform lavaan, so I just have to interpret my results based on the PROCESS analysis. What would you conclude based on this info? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

First, I agree with Shawn's comment (both parts).  And the FAQ for `PROCESS` also agrees, saying that `PROCESS` is for observed variables.  I would first recommend a) Learning `lavaan` or b) Hiring someone (I used to be a statistical consultant and many of my students were PhD candidates doing their dissertations) or c) Doing a different problem.

But, let's suppose that you need to analyze this particular problem and you do not have time to learn lavaan or other latent variable programs. Then, here's what I would do (acknowledging the issues with MLR that Shawn alludes to):

1. Do a regression with just the independent and dependent variables.
2. Do one that adds the mediator.
3. Look at the size of the difference in the coefficient for the independent variable, relative to its size in 1., and also to its actual values. That's the amount of mediation that is happening. Never mind significance.
4. For another look at the effect of adding the mediator, look at predicted values for the DV in the two models and how much they differ for the same input.
5. If possible (and it may not be) add covariates that might account for some of the noise in your model. Do this for both models 1 and 2.

Also, in your comment, you seem to be conflating "no significant effect" with "no effect". They aren't the same. And lower reliability makes it harder to find significance (it will also bias the coefficient estimates towards 0). You might try to figure some estimate of the reliability of the measures.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed response during this holiday, Peter!  They didnt tell me that Process was only for variables that were proven already, thanks for letting me know!Your procedure is doable in the short amount of time I have left, but what if similar results arise from the seperate regressions? I forgot to mention that I also put 5 covariates in the PROCESS analysis and that my N=1153

Comment: If the results are similar then there is little or no mediation